# Пишем "-го", говорим "-во"

Tags: фонетика

"Русского языка", но говорим мы "русскоВо языка". Собственно, об этом и вопрос.
Я никогда раньше не задумывалась: а откуда такое сильное несовпадение написания и произношения? А сто лет назад писалось бы вообще "русскаго".
Можно объяснить это тем, что "кого" произносить менее удобного, чем "ково", но почему же тогда письменный вариант не подогнать к устному (хотя я понимаю, что в этом плане до французов нам все-таки далеко))))
Но все-таки интересно, в чем причина замены Г на В и когда она произошла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Русская письменная культура имеет длительную историю, и это отразилась в различных правилах орфографии. Написание многих русских слов поддерживается традицией: мы пишем их так, как сотни лет назад. Например, после шипящих **ж**,**ш** принято писать букву **и**: *жить, шить* (хотя эта буква произносится как *ы*, потому что шипящие в русском языке твердые); в прилагательных в форме родительного падежа единственного числа пишется окончание ***-ого, -его: большого, хорошего*** (хотя вместо г произносится в). В таких случаях правила правописания слов диктуются традицией. Подробнее об этом можете прочитать в предусловии к книге "Домашний репетитор. Русский язык. Орфография. Пунктуация". Д.Э. Розенталь. И.Б. Голуб.